# What command means "do nothing" in a conditional in Bash?

Tags: bash, conditional-statements, no-op

Sometimes when making conditionals, I need the code to do nothing, e.g., here, I want Bash to do nothing when `$a` is greater than "10", print "1" if `$a` is less than "5", otherwise, print "2":

```
if [ "$a" -ge 10 ]
then
elif [ "$a" -le 5 ]
then
    echo "1"
else
    echo "2"
fi
```

This makes an error though. Is there a command which will do nothing and also not slow down my script?

Comment: `echo $[a<=5?1:2]` a brief ternary does it, ignoring any test for `a>=10`

Comment: @roblogic, why would you use ancient/deprecated/nonstandard ksh syntax when there are standardized options (`$((a <= 5 ? 1 : 2))`) available?

Comment: `$[]` *is* supported in bash, but yes `$(())` is probably better. I like to be brief.

Answer (score 531, accepted):

The no-op command in shell is `:` (colon).

```
if [ "$a" -ge 10 ]
then
    :
elif [ "$a" -le 5 ]
then
    echo "1"
else
    echo "2"
fi
```

From the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins):

> `:` (a colon)
>   Do nothing beyond expanding arguments and performing redirections. The return status is zero.

Comment: @SaintHax No, it doesn't run `true`. It's built into the shell, and does nothing.

Comment: it is shell built in (you are correct), it returns true (status 0) just like true does, and it is more difficult to read.  Bash is a DevOps language, and if `:` is written by someone on my team, I'd have them change it.

Comment: @SaintHax If someone used `true` in a non-conditional context, I'd have them change it. `if true` is fine, `then true` seems wrong.

Comment: Of course, you can simply rewrite the code to use `if ! condition; then do something; fi` instead of `if condition; then :; else do something; fi`.

Comment: I agree with you.  This example could be written if/elif/else using compound conditions and would be better.

Comment: @Barmar maybe it's usefull in this case  while (condition) do : done

Comment: @kingsjester The code is not on a loop, hence `while <cond>` is not useful

Comment: @alper of course not in this specific case (here you can avoid : by using the code proposed by barmar), but more generally,  if you need to wait until a condition is false, you can use the while (condition) do : done

Comment: E.g. `while ! ping -c 1 hostname; do : done` to wait for ping to succeed. @kingsjester

Comment: (err, `do :; done`, there -- `:` doesn't get special parsing rules, it still needs to be terminated with a newline or other command separator)

Answer (score 63):

You can probably just use the `true` command:

```
if [ "$a" -ge 10 ]; then
    true
elif [ "$a" -le 5 ]; then
    echo "1"
else
    echo "2"
fi
```

An alternative, in your example case (but not necessarily everywhere) is to re-order your if/else:

```
if [ "$a" -le 5 ]; then
    echo "1"
elif [ "$a" -lt 10 ]; then
    echo "2"
fi
```

Comment: If you don't test the result both `true` and `false` are effectively no-ops as far as the script is concerned, but in principle they *could* fork in some shells that accept this syntax so perhaps `:` is better.

Comment: The question is tagged bash. In bash, `true` and `false` are built-ins. For older shells, `true`, `false`, and even `:` might be external commands (though you'd probably see the latter only in *very* old shells).

Comment: I prefer `:` simply because it is more explicit what the intent is

Comment: The result `false` may not be a no-op, because if `set -e` is used (exit on non-zero) then `false` will cause the script to exit immediately.  `true` is a better no-op. `:` is a real no-op, but I have to agree that it is unreadable and I've been programming bash for 30 years and I didn't know about it...

Answer (score 12):

Although I'm not answering the original question concering the no-op command, many (if not most) problems when one may think "*in this branch I have to do nothing*" can be bypassed by simply **restructuring the logic** so that this branch won't occur.

I try to give a general rule by using the OPs example

> do nothing when $a is greater than "10", print "1" if $a is less than "5", otherwise, print "2"

we have to avoid a branch where `$a` gets more than 10, so `$a < 10` as a general condition can be applied to every other, following condition.

In general terms, when you say *do nothing when X*, then rephrase it as **avoid a branch where X**. Usually you can make the avoidance happen by simply negating X and applying it to all other conditions.

So the OPs example with the rule applied may be restructured as:

```
if [ "$a" -lt 10 ] && [ "$a" -le 5 ]
then
    echo "1"
elif [ "$a" -lt 10 ]
then
    echo "2"
fi
```

Just a variation of the above, enclosing everything in the `$a < 10` condition:

```
if [ "$a" -lt 10 ]
then
    if [ "$a" -le 5 ]
    then
        echo "1"
    else
        echo "2"
    fi
fi
```

(For this specific example [@Flimzys restructuring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17583590/1807643) is certainly better, but I wanted to give a general rule for all the people searching how to do nothing.)

Comment: One reason someone might want to have a no-op is when initially structuring the code with the idea that one will add the "add something here later" without having inadvertent side effects.  E.g. if one is putting an if-then-else-fi in a .bashrc, if you put  `echo "put stuff here"` it'll break some of the non-login uses (e.g. scp gets broken), and only whitespace/comments causes a runtime error.

Comment: Also, personally, I prefer to write code that is more "human friendly". It's often possible to restructure code to be more concise or even efficient. But when that's not critical, I prefer my code to be more readable for whichever developer comes along afterwards. (I also like commenting my code.)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that there is no other way than writing your own `nop` as a function. `:` does not the intended job, as it affects the exit status; maybe you'll find a builtin in the manual that does not change the exit status, but I've failed to exhibit such a one. You may say:

```
nop() { return; } # may return $?
bad() { return 42; }

bad; nop; echo $? # "nop" does nothing and keeps status; echo echoes 42
bad; :  ; echo $? # ":" does nothing but changes status; echo echoes 0
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of :, true, false I use

```
echo -n ""
```

It avoid empty line in terminal

You could also do it more concisely as:

```
echo -n
```

Comment: `echo -n` is listed in the POSIX specification as explicitly undefined behavior (see the APPLICATION USAGE section of https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html spelling this out), and even if you 100% know your shell is bash, it still can change behavior on runtime flags (see `shopt -s xpg_echo` and how its behavior meshes with `set -o posix` -- moreover, both those flags can be set by environment variables even if your code never actually runs them).