# Absolute value of a number

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I want to take the absolute of a number by the following code in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter the first file name: "
read first

echo "Enter the second file name: "
read second

s1=$(stat --format=%s "$first")
s2=$(stat -c '%s' "$second")

res= expr $s2 - $s1

if [ "$res" -lt 0 ]
then
        res=$res \* -1
fi

echo $res
```

Now the problem I am facing is in the if statement, no matter what I changes it always goes in the if, I tried to put `[[ ]]` around the statement but nothing.

Here is the error:

```
./p6.sh: line 13: [: : integer expression expected
```

Comment: one of the easier ways could be adding extra line after calculating the $res 
    res=`echo $res | tr -d -`

Comment: why not `res=$(s2 - s1); res=${res#-}`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$ s2=5 s1=4
$ echo $s2 $s1
5 4
$ res= expr $s2 - $s1
1
$ echo $res
```

What's actually happening on the fourth line is that `res` is being set to nothing and exported for the `expr` command. Thus, when you run `[ "$res" -lt 0 ]` `res` is expanding to nothing and you see the error.

You could just use an [arithmetic expression](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr):

```
$ (( res=s2-s1 ))
$ echo $res
1
```

Arithmetic context guarantees the result will be an integer, so even if all your terms are undefined to begin with, you will get an integer result (namely zero).

```
$ (( res = whoknows - whocares )); echo $res
0
```

Alternatively, you can tell the shell that `res` is an integer by declaring it as such:

```
$ declare -i res
$ res=s2-s1
```

The interesting thing here is that the right hand side of an assignment is treated in arithmetic context, so you don't need the `$` for the expansions.

Comment: @AliSajid no, the _error_ is at `if`. The _problem_ is before `if`, when you never actually assign a value to `res`.

Comment: abs $res => `${res/#-/}` :)

Comment: @rici heh. I thought of that, but ruled it out because OP said _by the following code_. But yeah…

Comment: @kojiro
`$ s2=5 s1=4`
`$ echo $s2 $s1`
`5 4`
`$ res= expr $s1 - $s2`
`-1`
`$ echo $res`
`{empty line}`

Comment: Sorry dude) Looks like you answer is outdated. Anyway rici answer helped me: `${VAR1#-}` works fine

Comment: Nah, my answer is not outdated. It's perfectly fine and helps OP understand the error they were getting. The _logic_ of OP's solution is perfectly fine for getting an absolute value. There are other solutions and that's cool too.

Answer (score 79):

You might just take `${var#-}`.

> `${var#Pattern}` Remove from `$var` the shortest part of `$Pattern` that matches the front end of `$var`. [tdlp](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html)

---

Example:

```
s2=5; s1=4
s3=$((s1-s2))

echo $s3
-1

echo ${s3#-}
1
```

Comment: This is great for getting a positive number out of `$(( 2**63 ))`.

Comment: I think this point by @ltrainpr is that bash overflows as a signed int at this number: care should be taken whether or not the absolute magnitude is computed. I mean: if you've already overflowed, you've already got a problem.

Answer (score 7):

I know this thread is WAY old at this point, but I wanted to share a function I wrote that could help with this:

```
abs() { 
    [[ $[ $@ ] -lt 0 ]] && echo "$[ ($@) * -1 ]" || echo "$[ $@ ]"
}
```

This will take any mathematical/numeric expression as an argument and return the absolute value.  For instance:  abs -4 => 4 or abs 5-8 => 3

Comment: `$(( ... ))` is the preferred syntax for arithmetic contexts rather than `$[ ... ]`. And this can be significantly simplified into a single arithmetic context: `abs() { echo $(( $1 > 0 ? $1 : -$1 )); }`

Answer (score 3):

I translated [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9772491/1695049) to bash. I like it more than the accepted string manipulation method or other conditionals because it keeps the `abs()` process inside the mathematical section

```
abs_x=$(( x * ((x>0) - (x<0)) ))

x=-3
abs_x= -3 * (0-1) = 3

x=4
abs_x= 4 * (1-0) = 4
```

Answer (score 2):

A workaround: try to eliminate the minus sign.

1. with [sed](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed)

```
x=-12
x=$( sed "s/-//" <<< $x )
echo $x

12
```

2. Checking the first character with [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

```
x=-12
[[ ${x:0:1} = '-' ]] && x=${x:1} || :
echo $x

12
```

This syntax is a [ternary opeartor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953645/ternary-operator-in-bash). The colon ':' is the [do-nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17583578/what-command-means-do-nothing-in-a-conditional-in-bash) instruction.

3. or substitute the '-' sign with nothing (again parameter expansion)

```
x=-12
echo ${x/-/}

12
```

Personally, scripting bash appears easier to me when I think `string`-first.

Answer (score 1):

This simple one works for floating point numbers:

`echo "sqrt($var^2)" | bc`

Comment: Hey! The solution with variable substitution is the best but yours is nice to implement a abs() function in `bc`.

Comment: I wonder if  it’s more costly than a "if below zero then multiply by minus one" ?

Answer (score 0):

For the purist, assuming  `bash` and a relatively recent one (I tested on 4.2 and 5.1):

```
abs() {
  declare -i _value
  _value=$1
  (( _value < 0 )) && _value=$(( _value * -1 ))
  printf "%d\n" $_value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the math and only the result matters, you may use

```
echo $res | awk -F- '{print $NF}'
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution:

```
res="${res/#-}"
```

Deletes only one `/` occurrence if `-` is at the first `#` character.

Comment: Sure its the simplest solution which is the solution oi the highest rated answer submitted 4+ years before yours ¯\_(ツ)_/¯