# Bash script to sum absolute values?

Tags: bash, math, git-bash

Is it possible to sum absolute values for integers entered into stdin and print the result to stdout?

So far I have is this:

```
read X
read Y
echo "$(($X+$Y))"
```

Can return:

```
11
11
22
```

But looking to get a result for absolutes. E.g:

```
-11
11
22
```

Comment: bash only supports an int, `bc` is an alternative

Comment: See this similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29223313/absolute-value-of-a-number

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Absolute value of a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29223313/absolute-value-of-a-number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider modified version, working on modern bash.

With temporary variable - note expression on let must be quoted, otherwise the special characters '<' will break the expression logic.

```
read x
read y
let s="(x<0?-x:x)+(y<0?-y:y)"
echo "SUM(abs($x)+abs($y))=$s"
```

Or without intermediate variable, using the '$((expr))' grammar. No need to quote.

```
read x
read y
echo "SUM(abs($x)+abs($y))=" "$(((x<0?-x:x)+(y<0?-y:y)))"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just strip the leading `-` from the variables:

```
read x
read y
echo "$((${x#-} + ${y#-}))"
```

This works since numbers in Bash are represented as strings.

Note that you should validate the user input (so the sign removal could be done there).