# compare variables irrespective of signage in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I want to compare two variables in `bash` and find if the variable is exceeding the cut_off value.

For example

cut_off value = 500.00

```
cut_off=500.00
```

Now I want to check a variable irrespective of its signage whether it exceeds the `cut_off` value or not

```
source_1=-510.00
target_1=1620.00

source_2=490.00
target_2=-488.13

source_3=5490.00
target_3=-4488.13
```

Now when ever the variables to check are greater than `cut_off` then `echo` saying `variable value is varying by` differenec of cut_off - variable to check`

I have done like below but it is not printing the correct error statement

```
cutoff=500.0

actual_diff=$(echo "${source}" - "${target}" | bc)

if (( $(echo "$actual_diff > $cutoff" |bc -l) ));
then
    echo -e "Difference between source and target is more than cut_off Actual difference is ${actual_diff}"
    exit 1
else
    echo -e "Difference between source and target is in cut_off range Actual difference is ${actual_diff}"
fi
```

Comment: what is cut_off range ? 0 to cutoff ?

Comment: @kalou.net it is between `-500.00 to 500.00`

Comment: so, If I understand correctly, you want to compare the "absolue value" of actual_diff to the "absolute value" of cut_off ..

Comment: @kalou.net yes that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so here is my proposition;

```
cutoff=500.0

actual_diff=$(echo "${source}" - "${target}" | bc)

if (( $(echo "${actual_diff#-} > ${cutoff#-}" |bc -l) ));

then
    echo -e "Difference between source and target is more than cut_off Actual difference is ${actual_diff}"
    exit 1
else
    echo -e "Difference between source and target is in cut_off range Actual difference is ${actual_diff}"
fi
```

(thanks to the following post [Absolute value of a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29223313/absolute-value-of-a-number))